# WebSphere wcm porlet content url rewrite

Tags: websphere, friendly-url, websphere-portal, websphere-6.1, wcm

I'm using WebSphere portal 6.0.1 and use it WCM to create an website. There is some page we use a portlet to show multiple content in it. So in the parent page

> `http://example.com/wps/portal/en/site/path/parent_page`

there will be a portlet show some smaller item. When user click on the item it redirect user to

> `http://example.com/wps/portal/en/site/path/parent_page/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hnd0cPE3MfAwMDZ2cLAyNzDx8T49BQQwMDU6B8JJK8u6-vG1A-1MI8yNUPLI9ft5d-VHpOfhLQnnCQzbhNsjDHLw-yCSRvgAM4Guj7eeTnpuoX5EZUBnvqOgIAX2ux9g!!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSWdrbUEhIS9JRFJBQUlpQ2dBek15cXchLzRCRWo4bzBGbEdpdC1iWHBBRUEhLzdfQ0dBSDQ3TDAwT1VPNzAyN1JRTjMyTzBPMDAvNF9fX185/?WCM_PORTLET=PC_7_CGAH47L00OUO7027RQN32O0O00_WCM&WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=/wps/wcm/connect/en/site/path/parent_page/small_item`

which will show item full content.

This long url is auto generate by  WCM it self. I discover that i can access the page in shorter url like

> `http://example.com/wps/portal/en/site/path/parent_page/?WCM_PORTLET=PC_7_CGAH47L00OUO7027RQN32O0O00_WCM&WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=/wps/wcm/connect/en/site/path/parent_page/small_item`

but this still not a friendly - url for SEO.

So I have these question:

- How can we make WCM generate url without !ut..... part?
- Can we make it even shorter like below using `.htaccess`?

> `http://example.com/wps/portal/en/site/path/parent_page/small_item`

or

> `http://example.com/wps/portal/en/site/path/parent_page/content-small_item`

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere Portal 6.0.* the only chance you have of simplifying portal pages is to give the portal pages a friendly name and then access the pages through those names. However, exactly how the portal chooses to generate its urls is within the product and not possible to change.

The direct WCM links will not get any better than what you just gave an example of.

This gets better in later versions of WebSphere Portal.